# Will I be granted a Swiss reunification Visa after I was refused a student visa?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, switzerland, family, weddings

I applied for a Swiss student's visa as a means to go and meet my fiance (we are both Cameroonians) but was refused as I come from a risk country (Cameroon). The reason for refusal was that they were not sure I will leave their country after studies.
Now, my fiance and I are getting married next month here in Cameroon and after that, apply for the Swiss family reunification visa.
Is there a possibility that the visa will be granted even after I had once been denied a student's visa?

Answer (score 6):

I am sure that the reunification visa is a permanent one, so it wouldn't make sense for the authorities to worried about you staying  longer than you should. That wasn't the case with the student visa, so since this is a different visa you shouldn't worry.